# How I can group a ASP.NET ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datatable

I want to Group my ASP.NET **ListView** but I don't know how I can do this :/ I get a string from a other program that have Information about Modules and Users that use a License from this. For this I want to use one **ListView** with Groups how this:

[image]

I need a simple example how I can do groups.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lv_lsdyna_programs" style="overflow:auto;height:160px;">
        <LayoutTemplate>
           <table id="UserList" border="0">

               <tr style="background-color:#ccdaeb">
                   <th><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Program_Header" runat="server" Text="Programm"></asp:Label></span> </th>
                   <th><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Used_Header" runat="server" Text="Belegt"></asp:Label></span></th>
                   <th><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Free_Header" runat="server" Text="Frei"></asp:Label></span></th>
                   <th><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Max_Header" runat="server" Text="Max"></asp:Label></span></th>
               </tr>
               <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
          </table>  
          </LayoutTemplate> 
          <ItemTemplate>
              <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#87CEFA'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'">
                  <td><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Program" Text='<%# Eval("Program") %>' runat="server"  /></span></td>
                  <td><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Used" Text='<%# Eval("Used") %>' runat="server" /></span></td>
                  <td><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Free" Text='<%# Eval("Free") %>' runat="server" /></span></td>
                  <td><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Max" Text='<%# Eval("Max") %>' runat="server" /></span></td>
              </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <AlternatingItemTemplate>
              <tr style="background-color: #E5EDF5;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#87CEFA'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#E5EDF5'">
                  <td><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Program" Text='<%# Eval("Program") %>' runat="server"  /></span></td>
                  <td><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Used" Text='<%# Eval("Used") %>' runat="server" /></span></td>
                  <td><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Free" Text='<%# Eval("Free") %>' runat="server" /></span></td>
                  <td><span class="spanpading"><asp:Label ID="lbl_Max" Text='<%# Eval("Max") %>' runat="server" /></span></td>
              </tr>
          </AlternatingItemTemplate>
          <EmptyDataTemplate>
                Zurzeit laufen keine Programme
          </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>    
</div>
```

In my code behind i use a **dataTable** that I fill with the Information and use this for the **ListView**.